# Do I need a ref keyword for this method?

Tags: c#

I want to update one object with the data from another, so something like:

```
User updatingUser = Users.Get(someId);

updatingUser.Name = otherUser.Name;
updatingUser.Age = otherUser.Age;
```

Now I want to create a method to perform this update, do I need a ref in the parameter list?

```
public static void UpdateUserFromUser(User original, User other)
{
  original.Name = other.Name;
  original.Age = other.Age;
  ..
  ..

}
```

Now the 'original' user passed in has properties on the object that are set, and that will not be updated, so this user object gets SOME properties updated.

I need a ref correct, like:

```
public static void UpdateUserFromUser(ref User original, User other)
```

Or will the object 'original' get updated without the need for ref?

Answer (score 3):

That depends whether User is a `struct` or a `class`. Classes are passed by reference, meaning that if User is a class, you don't need the `ref` keyword to update the original object. Structs are passed by value, which means you need to use `ref` if you are to update it.

Answer (score 2):

If `User` is a class, there is no need for the `ref` keyword as classes are reference types. There *is* actually a subtle difference in behavior if you use `ref`, but in your case it is not necessary since you are not modifying the variable; rather you are modifying the properties of the object that it refers to.

Comment: @Blankman: `ref` on a reference type allows you to modify which object in memory the variable points to. This explains it succinctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961717/c-what-is-the-use-of-ref-for-reference-type-variables

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` isn't required (assuming `User` is a class).