# "ref" keyword and reference types

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, ref, reference-type

someone in my team stumbled upon a peculiar use of the ref keyword on a reference type

```
class A { /* ... */ } 

class B
{    
    public void DoSomething(ref A myObject)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Is there any reason someone sane would do such a thing? I can't find a use for this in C#

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961717/c-what-is-the-use-of-ref-for-reference-type-variables).

Comment: Indeed, I missed that question while searching. Good catch

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let

```
class A
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}

void Do (ref A a)
{
    a = new A { Blah = "Bar" };
}
```

then

```
A a = new A { Blah = "Foo" };
Console.WriteLine(a.Blah); // Foo
Do (ref a);
Console.WriteLine(a.Blah); // Bar
```

---

But if just

```
void Do (A a)
{
    a = new A { Blah = "Bar" };
}
```

then

```
A a = new A { Blah = "Foo" };
Console.WriteLine(a.Blah); // Foo
Do (a);
Console.WriteLine(a.Blah); // Foo
```

Comment: +1 for an explicit example of what Oded is talking about, even if it was already fairly clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes it crystal clear!

Answer (score 16):

Only if they want to change the *reference* to the object passed in as `myObject` to a different one.

```
public void DoSomething(ref A myObject)
{
   myObject = new A(); // The object in the calling function is now the new one 
}
```

Chances are this is not what they want to do and `ref` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` keyword is usefull if the method is supposed to change the reference stored in the variable passed to the method. If you do not use `ref` you can not change the reference only changes the object itself will be visible outside the method.

```
this.DoSomething(myObject);
// myObject will always point to the same instance here

this.DoSomething(ref myObject);
// myObject could potentially point to a completely new instance here
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing peculiar with this. You reference variables if you want to return several values from a method or just don't want to reassign the return value to the object you've passed in as an argument.

Like this:

```
int bar = 4;
foo(ref bar);
```

instead of:

```
int bar = 4;
bar = foo(bar);
```

Or if you want to retrieve several values:

```
int bar = 0;
string foobar = "";
foo(ref bar, ref foobar);
```

Comment: In fact, OP is talking about reference types, not value types, like `int`

Comment: So you're saying references is not used with value types?

Comment: afaik, no. value types are fully copied every time, i.e. by value. that's why they are called value types

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. I never thought about that the OP used an actual object. I was very tired when reading it in the first place, being up for 24+ hours straight.