# Does it make sense to pass a "reference type" to a method as a parameter with 'ref' key?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, parameters, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: What is the use of “ref” for Reference-type variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961717/c-what-is-the-use-of-ref-for-reference-type-variables)

Hi,

Does it make sense to pass a "reference type" to a method as a parameter with 'ref' key?

Or it is just nonsense as it is already a reference type but not a value type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It lets you change the reference variable *itself*, in addition to the object it's *pointing to*.

It makes sense if you think you might make the variable point to a different object (or to `null`) inside your method.

Otherwise, no.

Comment: So, if I DO NOT pass as with 'ref' keyword and if I change its reference to null, then I return ffrom the method the object won't be null; correct?

Comment: @pencilCake: The reference won't be null, no. (An *object* is never "null".)

Comment: So only in the scope of the method it will be behaved as it is null but once the method is left, it will still be as it was -not null-?

Answer (score 3):

If makes a difference, because it allows the method to change the instance your variable is **pointing to**.

In other words, you use it when you want to make your variable point to a **different instance** of your reference type.

```
private static void WithoutRef(string s)
{
    s = "abc";
}

private static void WithRef(ref string s)
{
    s = "abc";
}

private static void Main()
{
    string s = "123";

    WithoutRef(s);
    Console.WriteLine(s); // s remains "123"

    WithRef(ref s);
    Console.WriteLine(s); // s is now "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When passing a reference type as *ref*, you are passing the reference as a reference, and this might make sense. It means that the method can replace the reference, if it wishes to:

```
public void CallRef()
{
    string value = "Hello, world";
    DoSomethingWithRef(ref value);
    // Value is now "changed".
}

public void DoSomethingWithRef(ref string value) 
{
    value = "changed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ref in C# allows you to modify the actual variable.

Check out this question - [What is the use of "ref" for reference-type variables in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961717/c-what-is-the-use-of-ref-for-reference-type-variables) - including this example

```
Foo foo = new Foo("1");

void Bar(ref Foo y)
{
    y = new Foo("2");
}

Bar(ref foo);
// foo.Name == "2"
```

Comment: ref in C# is the same as ByRef in VB, no difference.

Comment: I've edited the text - decided it was confusing anyways - and included the example from the duplicate question.

Comment: @Stuart: Took off my downvote. :)

Comment: It's cool - good to learn - think I'd misunderstood something in VB - I'm a C++ coder at heart :)

Comment: Not sure what the original answer said, as there's no edit history. But Mehrdad is indeed correct. `ByRef` in VB.NET is equivalent to C#'s `ref`. `ByVal` in VB.NET is equivalent to omitting a qualifier in C#, as passing by value is the default in both languages.

Comment: +1 back to you for pointing out the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

It does if you want the incoming variable that is being passed in to have its pointer changed.

Comment: @phoog: To regard references as pointers is a fairly good analogy. What do you think the relevant difference is here in this case?

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'm paraphrasing Eric Lippert. For one thing, pointers identify a memory address, so you need to pin the pointer's target so the GC won't move it. Also, from the 2nd link below, a pointer variable is for "[manipulating] a variable itself as data, rather than manipulating the value of that variable as data." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/07/references-and-pointers-part-one.aspx; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/10/references-and-pointers-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not nonsense. When you do that, you're passing the reference by reference.

Example:

```
class X
{
     string y;
     void AssignString(ref string s)
    {
        s = "something";
    }
    void Z()
    {
        AssignString(ref this.y};
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following code. What do you expect shall be the output from this program?

```
string s = "hello world";
Console.WriteLine(s);

foo(s);
Console.WriteLine(s);

bar(ref s);
Console.WriteLine(s);

void foo(string x)
{
    x = "foo";
}

void bar(ref string x)
{
    x = "bar";
}
```

The output is:

```
hello world
hello world
bar
```

When calling the method `bar`, you're passing the reference to string `s` by reference (instead of by value), which means that `s` will then change at the call site.