# What is the advantage of using the ref keyword with a reference type parameter?

Tags: c#, reference, ref

What do I gain, as the developer, by passing a reference type argument to a method using the ref keyword **if you are not changing what the reference points to**?

I have read both, [ref keyword with reference type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057213/ref-keyword-with-reference-type-parameter) and [What is the use of "ref" for reference-type variables in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961717/what-is-the-use-of-ref-for-reference-type-variables-in-c) and a number of others. I am aware this *subject* has been asked about and answered a great number of times. I believe I am asking a unique question. Feel free to mark down my question if you know other wize.

Simple class:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string first, string last)
    {
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
    }
}
```

Form passing using keyword ‘ref’:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Person _person;

    public Form2()
    {
        _person = new Person("John", "Doe");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = _person.ToString();

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLastName(ref _person);

        textBox2.Text = _person.ToString();
    }

    private static void ChangeLastName(ref Person person)
    {
        person.LastName = "Smith";
    }
}
```

Form passing parameter without using keyword ‘ref’:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Person _person;

    public Form2()
    {
        _person = new Person("John", "Doe");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = _person.ToString();

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLastName(_person);

        textBox2.Text = _person.ToString();
    }

    private static void ChangeLastName(Person person)
    {
        person.LastName = "Smith";
    }
}
```

What is the difference if any or what as a developer do I gain from the former (other than the ability to new up the passed parameter inside my method)?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you actually encounter code that passes by reference, but doesn't change the reference?

Comment: @chris, I have, many times. It's usually code written by people who don't understand the difference between ref/value types and ref/value parameters.

Comment: yeah - question sounds like "what is better ++i or i++?"

Comment: No, @Chris I am wondering if I should change it. Is that way "More Correct" (I hate writing like that) than not using ref?

Comment: The only difference (from an IL point of view) is an extra `ldind.ref` to indirectly load the address of the object (and even then ; the JIT ***might*** delete it if it's able to detect there was no assignment)

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JFa6P0), hope it helps

Comment: @GianPaolo OP explicitely stated "if you are not changing what the reference points to"

Comment: You are right @Sehnsucht, I missed the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What do I gain, as the developer, by passing a reference type argument to a method using the ref keyword if you are not changing what the reference points to?

None whatsoever - that's the only purpose of passing a reference type by reference is if you are going to change what the reference refers to.

To be fair - it gives you the ability to *change* that behavior in the future, which would be sadistic and cruel...

Comment: On top of not gaining anything, I would say you lose. Now that the `ref` is there, readers expect the reference to be changed in some way because why would it be there otherwise? Learning that the reference is never changed is a surprise and takes the reader out of their groove.