# c# Reference-Type by ref - Address to an Address?

Tags: c#, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

trying to understand what exactly happens, if I pass a Reference-Type by its reference. I understand it this way:

So I have a Class Foo, which represents a Reference-Type

```
class Foo{ //Foo-stuff here }
```

So with this right here

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

`Foo f` (created on the Stack) holds the address/reference of the actual Object, which is created in the Heap when calling `new Foo()`;

so `f` actually holds something like `0x2A53BC`

If I call a Method doing this

```
void Test(Foo g) { g = null; }
```

I just pass the address of the "address-variable/reference-variable" `f`. So `g` actually points to `f` in the Stack but NOT to the actual Object in the Heap. So I can change propertys of the Foo Object in Heap through `f`, because I have the Address of `f`, I can access Foo through `f`, but setting `g=null` just kills the Address to the `f` variable in Stack, not the reference to the object in Heap itself.

but with this

`void Test(ref Foo g) { g = null; }`

Im actually working with the real address of that Foo-Object in the Heap, so with `0x2A53BC`. That means, I can change where it points to or Kill the pointer from Stack to Heap by setting `g=null`

Is this right? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `Foo` is a `class` type, in particular a reference type. And you have:

```
var f = new Foo();
```

so the *value* of `f` is really a *reference* to the actual object. And as you say, we may think of the reference as an integer, say `0x2A53BC` (just to make it concrete, we do not really have access to the integer or whatever the *reference* really is; there is no pointer arithmetic with these references).

Now, when you *pass by value*, as with the overload:

```
void Test(Foo g) { g = null; }
```

which we call with `Test(f);`, the value `0x2A53BC` will be ***copied*** to a new storage location (a new place on the stack), and that new storage location becomes `g`. If you had used `g` to mutate the existing instance, then since  both storage locations hold identical information `0x2A53BC`, you would have mutated the instance pointed to also by `f`. But instead you choose to assign to `g`. That leads to a the new storage location for `g` holding now the reference `0x000000` (we simply assume that zero is used as the representation for `null`). It clearly will not change the storage location for `f` which still points to the original instance located at `0x2A53BC`.

In contrast, with the other overload:

```
void Test(ref Foo g) { g = null; }
```

which we call with `Test(ref f);`, we *pass by reference*. So the **same storage location** is used for `g` as we already had for `f`. The value `0x2A53BC` is not copied. When you assign `g = null;`, that is the *original* `0x2A53BC` being overwritten with `0x000000` (the magic representation of `null`). When the method returns, yes even before it returns, `f` has changed its value to point to the new "place" `0x000000`.

To sum up: The "value" of a reference type is the reference. When passed by value, a copy of the reference "number" is made and used by the invoked method. When passed by reference, the value is not copied, the same storage location is used by the callee method and the caller method.

---

Addition: Some quotes from the C# spec:

> 5.1.4 Value parameters
>
> A parameter declared without a `ref` or `out` modifier is a
>   ***value parameter***.
>
> A value parameter comes into existence
>   upon invocation of the function member (method, instance constructor,
>   accessor, or operator) or anonymous function to which the parameter
>   belongs, and is initialized with the value of the argument given in
>   the invocation. A value parameter normally ceases to exist upon return
>   of the function member or anonymous function. [...]
>
> 5.1.5 Reference parameters
>
> A parameter declared with a `ref` modifier is a ***reference parameter***.
>
> A
>   reference parameter does not create a new storage location. Instead, a
>   reference parameter represents the same storage location as the
>   variable given as the argument in the function member or anonymous
>   function invocation. Thus, the value of a reference parameter is
>   always the same as the underlying variable. [...]

Comment: Old related thread: [What is the use of “ref” for reference-type variables in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961717/)

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

> I just pass the address of the "address-variable/reference-variable" `f`. So `g` actually points to `f` in the Stack but NOT to the actual Object in the Heap.

Actually you have it backwards. When you don't use `ref` g will have the value of `f` (in your example `0x2A53BC`) ***copied*** in to a new variable named `g`. `g` and `f` are totally independent of each other, but they both hold the "value" `0x2A53BC`. When you do `g = null;` the variable `f` will still hold `0x2A53BC` but g will now hold `0x000000`.

**NOTE: I am not sure about this next part, I may be telling you factually incorrect information, but I am describing the correct behavior from the outside observer.**
When you use `ref` the variable `g` will point at the address of the value of `f` (lets say `0x154AFA`) and that `f` still points at `0x2A53BC`. When you do `g = null;` the value of `g` does not get updated, it still points at `0x154AFA`, however `f` will now point at `0x000000`